# --add-host parameter in Marathon docker application

Tags: json, docker, hosts, mesos, marathon

I have docker images (with entrypoints) that I would like to run using Mesos and Marathon. These images require changes in /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf. When I typically run this I would do something like:

```
docker run --add-host host:ip --dns-search url image
```

but in a marathon application (which i'm setting up as a json body to be sent to marathon), I have no idea what these options would be mapped to. For instance `-p` becomes `portMappings` in the json body. Does anybody know what the `--add-host` and `--dns-search` and potentially other options would become?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may pass them in `parameters` like that:

```
"container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
        "network": "HOST",
        "image": "your/image",
        "parameters": [
            { "key": "add-host", "value": "host:ip" },
            { "key": "dns-search", "value": "url" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Refer [here](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html), "Privileged Mode and Arbitrary Docker Options" section for details.

Comment: Can we use `publish` key and how does it work with `portMapping` ?